# Notifying system of Edge shutdown via extension

Tags: microsoft-edge-extension

When a user closes the last tab/window I do get an event indicating that, however it seems all other APIs are non-functioning so I can't send a nativeEvent for example to a companion UWP app to notify the rest of the system of Edge closing via user action.  Is there some recommended approach to this sort of thing where I want to notify other aspects of our system that edge is closing?